# Selenium and a Non-working IEDriverServer

Tags: selenium

The `IEDriverServer` is throwing a `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException` when I try a simple navigation to a page. This is working for Firefox.

It is "Unexpected error" and if I read further along it appears to be a 404 page not found.

I have already disabled protected mode for all zones and had also made `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true` on the `InternetExplorerOptions` object.

How does one get IE working in this case?

**Edit**
Here is the stacktrace:

> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(InternetExplorerDriverService
>   service, InternetExplorerOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
>   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(InternetExplorerDriverService
>   service, InternetExplorerOptions options)    at
>   CUWebinars.Selenium.Core.Ie.IeTestDriver..ctor() in
>   e:\TTS\BankWebinars\CUWebinars.Selenium.Core\Ie\IeTestDriver.cs:line
>   21    at CUWebinars.WebUi.Tests.Ie.IeBaseTest.Setup() in
>   e:\TTS\BankWebinars\CUWebinars.WebUi.Tests\Ie\IeBaseTest.cs:line 13

**Edit 2**
The following is in the constructor of the IeTestDriver (custom class)

```
const string ieTestDriverLocation = @"E:\";
var internetExplorerDriverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(ieTestDriverLocation);
var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();

internetExplorerDriverService.Port = 333; // this is the port for the driver, not the webpage            
port = "5556"; // in base class

webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerDriverService, internetExplorerOptions); // crashes here
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: @user1177636 I have edited the question to add the stacktrace. Note, I have protection enabled for ALL zones and am using IE 11.

Comment: Show us your code that fails. What is the URL that you are trying to browse to? Have you prefixed `http://` to the url?

Comment: @Faiz It is crashing before it gets to the navigate code. It is crashing upon newing up of InternetExplorerDriver object. See edit in question.

Comment: @user1177636 Note it is crashing also with the Chrome version of the webdriver.

Comment: @onefootswill: Does the error message have anything after "Unexpected error"? Have you copied IEDriverServer.exe to `E:`?

Comment: @Faiz It does. It is basically the XHTML of the 404 page that something is returning. Probably too big to paste here. I can paste somewhere elsewhere if you'd like to peruse it.

Comment: @onefootswill: Just noticed you are using IE 11. Ensure you also have set Enhanced Protected Mode turned off. IE 11 seems to be currently unsupported, see [Issue 6511](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6511)

Comment: @Faiz I have tried that. Note, I'm seeing the same behaviour with the Chrome webdriver.

Comment: @onefootswill: my last suggestion :) Try using a different port (eg:5555), or not specifying one, as the port 333 falls within the _Well-known ports_ range. If you dbl-click IEDriverServer.exe, it should give you a _Listening on port <number>_ message (atleast to check that the IEDriverServer works).

Comment: @Faiz Great suggestion. I double-clicked on each exe and that told me what ports they were listening on. I thought that was something which I was meant to set. I changed the ports to those respective ports and it worked. Kudos!

Comment: @onefootswill: Great, have added an answer with this information for you to accept, and for others to know what worked.

Comment: @Faiz No worries. I've been experimenting and setting the ports to other numbers which are outside the well-known ports range. Seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port `333` specified for the `InternetExplorerDriverService` falls within the [well-known-port-numbers](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/well-known-port-numbers) range:

> On most systems, a well-known port number can only be used by a system
>   (root) process or by a program run by a privileged user.

Allow the driver service to select its own port by not specifying one explicitly, or provide an available port.

Double clicking IEDriverServer.exe will give you a `Listening on port <number>` message to see what it automatically picks up as available.